# Marshall mg 4 pedal and code 50 amp

Tags: learning, amplifiers

I bought a Marshall CODE50 amp and they sent me an mg 4 pedal with it. Is there any way to make it work with the CODE50, and what is the difference?

Comment: That would be a good question to Marshall. All I can see in the website is that MG Stompware footswitch is dedicated for MG4 series amps. Perhaps they sent you wrong footwitch by mistake?

Comment: Since it all appears to be brand new, reference to the supplier would be a far better bet than anything suggested here.

Comment: Definitely contact your retailer or Marshall, but checking the [CODE 50 specs](https://marshall.com/amps/products/amps/code/code50), I see that the compatible footswitches are [PEDL-91010](https://marshall.com/amps/products/footswitches/pedl-91010) and [PEDL-91009](https://marshall.com/amps/products/footswitches/pedl-91009).  The MG4 pedal is model [PEDL-90008](https://marshall.com/amps/products/footswitches/pedl-90008).  It sounds like they shipped the wrong accessory.